# AVCaptureVideoOutput and compression

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

As of iOS 4.x, is AVCaptureVideoDataOutput configurable to return you compressed frames?

The documentation for AVCaptureVideoDataOutput says:

> AVCaptureVideoDataOutput is a concrete
>   sub-class of AVCaptureOutput you use,
>   via its delegate, to process
>   uncompressed frames from the video
>   being captured, or to access
>   compressed frames.

One of the properties is 'videoSettings' which according to the SDK, is the compression settings for the output and it says the compression setting keys can be found in AVVideoSettings.h. But it also says that only CVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey is supported.

Based on this, can I assume that all of the frames returned by AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to the sampleBufferDelegate method is uncompressed? Is there a way to get to the compressed frames?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the SDK only returns uncompressed frames from the camera. Maybe it'll change in the future, but it's like this right now. Therefore, the only way to get compressed images is to do it yourself. How to do it depends on your needs.

If you need to write them on disk, it will be long and ineffective (a movie would be better). If you need to send compressed images OTA, it's doable with a jpeg or png library for example.

Comment: I would like to send the frames (and accompanying audio) over the wire to a server and compression is a necessity as is speed for the total operation. Thus saving to disk would cause overall delays. Would you still use a jpeg or png compression library or something else? Is there another good option such as working directly with CMBlockBuffer that can be returned by the sampleBufferDelegate?

Comment: @Steve Card: I'm not sure you really need compression, it depends on your connexion to the server and what you do with images on it. I think you don't have other options than using Core Media buffers (I'm not used to audio) returned by the buffer delegates. This is the fastest and it can be done in a thread. Estimate the size of the overall stream and your needs on bandwidth and computation, you'll know what to do.